# postgresql 9.2.4 hstore search keys Unknown operator

Tags: postgresql, search, key, hstore

Can't use ?| operator. Works fine with postgresql 9.1.9 (development), fails on 9.2.4 (production)

```
test=# SELECT 'a=>1,b=>2'::hstore ?| ARRAY['b','c'];
ERROR:  operator does not exist: hstore ?| text[]
LINE 1: SELECT 'a=>1,b=>2'::hstore ?| ARRAY['b','c'];
                                   ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

hstore is installed

```
test=# create extension hstore;
ERROR:  type "hstore" already exists
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message from `create extension hstore` indicates that you don't actually have the *extension* `hstore` installed, just some parts of its contents.  (Otherwise the error message would be `extension "hstore" already exists`.)  So I suggest you fix your hstore installation.  It might work to do `CREATE EXTENSION hstore FROM unpackaged`.  If not, you will have to do manual surgery to remove or add the missing parts.

Comment: CREATE EXTENSION hstore FROM unpackaged;
    ERROR:  function hstore_recv(internal) does not exist

Comment: I think it's broken after postgresql upgrade from 8.x